# How do you kill children?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If you've been playing a decent amount of Skyrim, you may have noticed that children are annoying. *Really* annoying. However, while trying to bash one of the little snots into the ground to teach him some manners, I noticed that they're invulnerable to damage.

Obviously, they're witches, or at the very least cheaters. Is there a console command to make them less invincible? If not, is there one that will shut them up?

Comment: Honestly, this question needs to be asked for most games.

Comment: Unrelenting force off a cliff :D

Comment: Pretty sure that without a mod this won't be possible, as I'd always heard it was due to censors/ratings. I guess it's viewed as bad taste, even in a game...

Comment: @domocus They'll land on their feet and run right back uphill. Little cockroaches.

Comment: It's satisfying nonetheless :D

Comment: @Domocus You're reminding me of the most inventive ways to kill the adoring fan in Oblivion ;). OP. Have you tried bringing up the console with the tilde key and then clicking on the NPC (which will give the Reference number of the NPC) and then typing in .kill after that number? Yes, it will kill them. It certainly makes them less invincible anyhow ;).

Comment: Fun Fact: You can play tag with the little girls in Whiterun. And then, when they inevitably win, you can be a sore loser, with the help of the mod below.

Comment: Wow. The title change on this question makes me look like a seriously heartless misanthrope.

Comment: Just a bit. I'm not really sure I agree with the edit, either, since my question was asked in pursuit of enabling physical abuse - or, in fundamentalist Evangelical terms, discipline - not necessarily murder. But whatever, probably helps more people this way.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz LOL what was the title before?  This is epic.

Comment: I think it was something along the lines of "How do I even the playing field between myself and children" as my original intent was simply to slap them around a bit with a club. However, everything seems to one-shot them, so chastisement has become quite the severe affair in Skyrim, these days.

Comment: Let's all admit it.  We've hit F5, tried, failed, reloaded, and Googled why.

Comment: You better be careful. Some crazy Canadian may take this question out of context and you'll end up in prison!

Comment: Definitely an issue when you get caught by one committing a crime and need to kill the witnesses... oh no you can't.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Console commands are too much effort.

Fortunately for us, there's a mod. The Killable Children mod:

> Allows the children of Skyrim to die. Affects the Breton, Imperial, Nord and Redguard children.

[image: Poor Mila.]

You can download it from Nexus Mods [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/774/?). (Note that Nexus Mods requires you to sign up for a free account for age verification purposes, I believe.)

Comment: I just installed this to make the game more realistic although I might not killed a kid on purpose. But I guess it makes an accidental dragon shout more funny... :)

Comment: The orphanage will never be the same...mwa ha ha.

Comment: Holy heavens. Jesus forgive me. Now I know why it was not included in-game. Mother of God.

Comment: Last night, I was dreaming about a Dead Thrall - the most horrible one I had ever seen.

Comment: Link dead.54321

Comment: @NiteCyper Link works for me.

Comment: @NiteCyper its not dead, you just need to register at nexusmods since its considered adult only content

Comment: Well now.  I guess I won't be sleeping tonight.

Comment: Regardless if console commands are too much effort, it's irrelevant - because you can't remove a kid's invincible status via the console - you at least need a mod created via the CK, if not changing the models themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Open the console (<kbd>`</kbd> by default). 
Type in `help <kidsNameGoesHere> 4`. You'll see a list of ID's, one of them will say something like:
`_NPC (somenumberswillbehere) kid'sname`
Next type in `SetEssential <thenumbersfrombefore> 0` at the console and hit <kbd>↲ Enter</kbd>.
Replace  with the kid's npcID, and he should be killable, unless Bethesda implemented their invulnerability in a unique way.

Comment: Okay, I think I might be stupid, but I cannot get this to work, no matter what combination of things I type in. It keeps telling me that either I've created a syntax error, I'm missing the parameter "actor base" or that the id I type in is an invalid item for "actor base." Could you maybe toss in an example of a string you typed in for this for a specific NPC?

Comment: Children aren't (just) Essential, they're invincible. Essential characters simply cannot be killed - but they can be damaged. Invincible characters don't even take damage. The only way to make a character not invincible is via the Creation Kit. However, if it's anything like the Fallout games, you may even have to replace the character models themselves as well.

Answer (score 2):

The mods, **[Killable children V2](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8754)** and **[Killable and Lootable Children](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/17849)** allow killing of children, but at the same time, setting as unkillable or 'essential', certain quest-related children, preventing bugs and avoiding missing some quests, which is like the vanilla Skyrim behavior where certain quest-related NPCs can not be killed.

The Killable and Lootable Children mod also allows you to loot children, and makes the 'essential' children, 'non-essential' when their related quests are finished.

[image: The mod in action.]

Comment: @NiteCyper It might be a server issue. I just tested it and the [first link](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/8754) works fine here. Also: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/8754

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the person or child while your console is open (<kbd>~</kbd>) then type `SetEssential 0`. Don't type `npcid` manually or you'll get errors most of the time. I have noticed that a lot of `npcids` are different between the 360 and PC version while some are still the same, so just click to target then type command without the need for the `npcid` specification.

Comment: First, SetEssential only works on the BaseID, not the RefID (you have to use: help "<npc name>" to get the BaseID). Second, although children may be essential, it's generally irrelevant - as they're all invincible. Meaning, unlike essential characters, they can't even be *damaged*. To change *that* you need to use the CK to create a mod.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill children in the PC version of skyrim by changing their races in the setrace commend. once you change them you can be able to kill them with the kill command to not get a bounty. this works if you want to kidnap a child WITHOUT teleporting. or you can download a mod that doesnt require doing this process.

Answer (score -1):

Just dual wield the spell "[Raise Zombie](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Raise_Zombie)" and cast it on the kid, they just crumble into ash.

Comment: ha ha that can't happen