# My daughter has a pet fox... Is it dangerous?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My adopted daughter adopted a fox and fearing for her safety (before a quick-save of course), I killed the fox and said daughter was mighty pissed at me...

To avoid a potential re-adoption for my ungrateful daughter, I quick-loaded and now I'm here for counselling:

**Is the fox safe to be a pet for my daughter? Will it grow in the near future and cause harm?**

Comment: I understand the reason for this question, but it is easily researched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading the [wiki entry on pets](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Pets_(Hearthfire)):

Fox pets (well ANY pet they might drag home) are completely harmless. They won't attack unless provoked.

Comment: So the pets don't grow right? They will remain small and not harmful for both me and the invincible kids right?

Comment: @NikhilEshvar It sounds like you're thinking a fox may grow into a wolf. They are different creatures.

Comment: Rookie mistake! Got it! I was thinking of the wolf too!

Answer (score 4):

The premise is incorrect.

Children are set to essential by default.  This makes them effectively invulnerable.

On top of that, they don't even take damage.

Unless you went around and modified your kids via the console, they can't even be hurt to begin with.

There's a reason why someone else asked "[How do you kill children?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37257/how-do-you-kill-children)"